# SwiftUI - My list doest not come all the way up to my navigation view

Tags: swift, list, navigationview

I can't seem to find the reason why there's a space between my list and navigation view. When I remove my navigation bar items, my list fills the space, when I have my navigation bar items, there's a gap between the navigation bar and my list. The style I'm using for my navigation bar is inline. Is this a bug in Xcode or is there something that I'm missing. Here's the code below.

...

```
import SwiftUI

struct DigitalReceiptContent: View {
    @ObservedObject var store = ReceiptStore()
    @State var showProfile = false
    
    func addUpdate() {
        store.updates.append(Update(name: "New Purchase", purchase: "$0.00", date: "00/00/21"))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
    NavigationView {
    
            List {
                ForEach(store.updates) { update in
                    NavigationLink(destination: FullDigitalReceipt(update: update))
                    {
                     
                        HStack {
                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)))
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.6), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 1)
                            
                            Text(update.name)
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                                .padding(.leading)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 4.0) {
                                Text(update.date)
                                    .font(.caption)
                                
                                Text(update.purchase)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1)))
                                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
                .onDelete{ index in
                    self.store.updates.remove(at: index.first!)
                }
                
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Purchases"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(
                // Selection button; organize purchases
                leading: EditButton(),
                
                trailing: Button(action: {self.showProfile.toggle() }) { Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showProfile) {
                    ProfileSettings()
                })
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

...

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are using `GroupedListStyle` which adds a header

Comment: Without the GroupedListStyle, my list doesn't take up the width of the full screen and it still doesn't take up the rest if the height. I added a screen shot without the GroupedListStyle.

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of using .navigationbarItem, use Toolbar and ToolbarItem :D